# Auto incrementing id value with string django

Tags: python, django, auto-increment

I am trying to create a model in which I have a case_id field. This field should be auto incrementing. But my case_id value should be in the format shown,

case_id=FAS150001 (This should be the first value)

```
class InformationRequest(models.Model):

    """Model to track information"""

    case_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    information = models.TextField()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charfields cannot be auto-incremented.

But [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/topics/signals/) can help you to simulate this behavior. You could do a pre-save or post-save signal for make it, for example:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import InformationRequest


@receiver(pre_save, sender=InformationRequest)
def my_handler(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    # Compute case_id, ex:
    # instance.case_id = increment_case_id()
```